# char to string c#

Tags: c#, строки, char

Очень нужна помощь, пожалуйста. Есть текст в richtextbox, который превращаю в массив символов. Дальше нужно пройтись по всему массиву символов и проверить нет ли знаков (можно только буквы, если знак удалить, я пока добавляю в textbox), затем нужно добавить в datagrid слово, которое состоит из букв без иных знаков (в нижнем регистре).
Проблема в том, что добавляется в datagrid в одну строку все слова и склеенные. Понимаю, что нужно разделить по пробелу, но так тоже не получается вывести нормально по одному слову в одну строку datagrid. 
Вот код:

```
...
string word;
    string str;
    private DataGridViewRow row;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var col1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(col1);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Word();
    }
    public bool Oper(char v)
    {

        if (("№:;'+-/*@^<>~`()%$ ={}&?!.,--#0123456789".IndexOf(v) != -1))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    public void Word()
    {
        char[] lines = richTextBox1.Text.ToCharArray();
        foreach (var s in lines)
        {
            if (!Oper(s) && s != ' ')
            {
                word += s;
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + s;
            }
        }
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(word.ToString().ToLower());

    }
}
```

}
[image: Вот что получается:]

Comment: `dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new String(richTextBox1.Text.Where(c=>char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray()).ToLower());` ?

Comment: Пробовала, не получается, сливается все в одну строку и добавляется в одну строку datagrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется, что разбивать строку на символы "вручную" и "вручную" их проверять не совсем корректно, лучше использовать методы LINQ.

Я посидел 2 минуты и сделал такую функцию (расширение):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string[] SplitOnWords(this string text)
    {            
        text = string.Join("", text.Select(symbol => Char.IsLetter(symbol) ? symbol : ' ')); // заменяет "небуквы" на пробел
        text = text.Trim().Replace("  ", " ").ToLower(); // удаляет лишние пробелы и переводит строку в нижний регистр          
        return text.Split(new char[] { ' ' }); // разделяет строку на слова
    }
}
```

Она возвращает массив слов, которые можно будет присвоить **dataGridView1** в цикле **foreach** по нажатию кнопки:

```
var words = richTextBox1.Text.SplitOnWords();

foreach (var word in words)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(word);
}
```

Про метод [.Select](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8).

Answer (score 1):

Я бы предложил работать через формирование списка токенов на основе изучаемого текста.
[image: пример работы]

Создадим такой интерфейс

```
public interface IToken
{
    //значение токена
    string Value { get; }
    //позиция первого символа токена в тексте
    int Position { get; }
    //название токена
    string TokenName { get; }
    //инфо для отображения
    string TokenValue { get; }
}
```

Вот пример класса для токена Пробела

```
public class SpaceToken : IToken
{
    public string Value { get; }
    public int Position { get; }
    public string TokenName { get; }
    public string TokenValue => $@"[{TokenName}:{Position}]";

    public SpaceToken(int position)
    {
        Position = position;
        Value = " ";
        TokenName = "space";
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return TokenName;
    }
}
```

А это для токена слова

```
public class WordToken : IToken
{
    public string Value { get; }
    public int Position { get; }
    public string TokenName { get; }
    public string TokenValue => $"<{Value}:{Position}:{OrderNumber}>";
    public int OrderNumber { get; }

    public WordToken(int position, string value, int orderNumber)
    {
        Position = position;
        Value = value.ToLower();
        TokenName = "word";
        OrderNumber = orderNumber;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value;
    }
}
```

Тогда текст можно превратить в токены так

```
public List<IToken> GetTokens(string text)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(text));

    //готовим результат
    List<IToken> tokens = new List<IToken>();

    //нумерация слов в тексте
    int wordsOrder = 0;
    //позиция первой буквы слова
    int wordPosition = 0;
    //для посимвольного набора слова
    List<char> wordChars = new List<char>();

    var chars = text.ToCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
    {
        //извлекаем текущий символ
        var current = chars[i];
        if (Char.IsLetter(current))
        {
            //если это первая буква слова
            if (wordChars.Count == 0)
            {
                wordPosition = i;
            }

            //вносим букву в массив слова
            wordChars.Add(current);

            //если это последний символ в тексте, т.е. текст заканчивается на слове
            //нужно добавить словный токен
            if (i + 1 == chars.Length)
            {
                AddWordToken(wordChars, wordPosition, tokens, ++wordsOrder);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //т.е. текущий символ не относится к слову
            //и до этого у нас возможно собиралось слово
            //и его нужно закрывать и создавать словный токен
            if (wordChars.Count > 0)
            {
                AddWordToken(wordChars, wordPosition, tokens, ++wordsOrder);
                //очищаем для следующего слова
                wordChars.Clear();
            }

            //добавляем небуквенный токен
            AddNotLetterToken(tokens, i, current);
        }
    }

    return tokens;
}

private void AddWordToken(List<char> wordChars, int position, List<IToken> tokens, int wordsOrder)
{
    var array = wordChars.ToArray();
    var word = new String(array);
    tokens.Add(new WordToken(position, word, wordsOrder));
}

private void AddNotLetterToken(List<IToken> tokens, int i, char current)
{
    if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(current))
    {
        tokens.Add(new SpaceToken(i));
        return;
    }

    if (Char.IsDigit(current))
    {
        tokens.Add(new NumberToken(i, current.ToString()));
        return;
    }

    //если это не пробел и не цифра, значит это какой-то знак
    tokens.Add(new SignToken(i, current.ToString()));
}
```

Ну, а далее уже будет достаточно просто работать с коллекцией токенов.

Пример целиком [здесь.](https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples/tree/master/WinFormsWords)

Answer (score 0):

Делим по пробелам, убираем лишнее

```
var words = richTextBox1.Text.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var word in words)
{
    var onlyLetters = new String(word.Where(c => char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray()).ToLower();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(onlyLetters))
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(onlyLetters);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Алена галочка для принятия ответа слева от вопроса